# Upload only files below a certains size and discard the others in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a form where the user can select multiple files to upload and some other fields. The client requested that we should validate file sizes client side and only upload files that pass the validation. If, for example, my limit is 1Mb and I select a 2Mb file and a 500Kb file, the upload should only send the second file to server. How can I do that?

I use Spring MVC so the form is mapped to a bean in the controller. I tried removing the files from the list that did not pass the validation (I control file.size for each) so that only the good ones remain but from my understanding the input file element is read only so no cigar. I also ditching the submit of the form and doing it via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        filesToUpload:$.grep($("#selectFileInput")[0].files, function(file, i){
            return(file.size <= 110000);
        }),
        notes:$('#uploadNotes').val(),
        selectedFlow:$("#fileType").find(":selected").val(),
        fileUtenteHidden:$('#fileUtenteHidden').val()
    },
    url: "uploadFiles",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false
});
```

Again, no success.

Any input is appreciated.

EDIT: here's the relevant snippets of code for both the jQuery part and the spring MVC controller:

```
$("#filesSubmit").click(function(event){

    //Validates the files
    var filesToUpload = $.grep($("#selectFileInput")[0].files, function(file, i){
        return(file.size <= 110000);
    });

    $.ajax({
        data: {
            filesToUpload:filesToUpload,
            notes:$('#uploadNotes').val(),
            selectedFlow:$("#fileType").find(":selected").val(),
            fileUtenteHidden:$('#fileUtenteHidden').val()
        },
        url: "uploadFiles",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        contentType : false
    });     

});
```

Controller:

```
    @Secured({SecurityConstants.UPLOAD_VIEW})
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView uploadFiles(@RequestParam("filesToUpload") List<MultipartFile> filesToUpload, @RequestParam("notes") String notes, @RequestParam("selectedFlow") String uploadType, @RequestParam("fileUtenteHidden") String fileUtenteHidden, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("START uploadFiles");

    System.out.println("PARTITO");

    UploadFileBean uploadFileBean = new UploadFileBean();

    uploadFileBean.setFiles(filesToUpload);
    uploadFileBean.setFileUtenteHidden(fileUtenteHidden);
    uploadFileBean.setNotes(notes);
    uploadFileBean.setUploadType(uploadType);

    UploadReport report = uploadManager.upload(uploadFileBean, userSession.getUsername(), userSession.getGroup());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("uploadedReport", report);

    LOG.info("END uploadFiles");
    return new RedirectView("/indexUploadFiles", true);
}
```

at the moment, it gets stuck at the ajax call without ever reaching the controller. The server output contains :

```
19:06:15.180 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing POST request for [/myProject/uploadFiles]
19:06:15.180 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /uploadFiles
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
19:06:15.181 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

pass this validated files to DATA(`filesToUpload:`)

```
var validatedFiles = [];
var files = $("#selectFileInput")[0].files;
files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.size <= 110000)
        validatedFiles.push(file);
});
```

or like this using PHP array

```
var postData = [];
$.each($('#selectFileInput')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    postData.append('filesToUpload[]', file);
});
postData.append('notes', $('#uploadNotes').val());
postData.append('selectedFlow', $("#fileType").find(":selected").val());
postData.append('fileUtenteHidden', $('#fileUtenteHidden').val());
```

and then `data: postData`